# invalid JWT error with timeframe using google-cloud-vision api on virtual windows

Tags: python, windows, google-cloud-platform, centos, virtualbox

I installed windows7 on the virtualbox to use google-cloud-vision api on the activeX web page on my CentOS server.

Using google-cloud-vision API for authentication, following error during authentication:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values and use a clock with skew to account for clock differences between systems.')
```

Windows Internet Time Sync, time is synchronized, but an error occurs.
but same code on normal Windows, no error occurs.

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
textImage.save(imgByteArr, format='PNG')
content = imgByteArr.getvalue()

image = types.Image(content=content)

response = client.text_detection(image=image)
labels = response.text_annotations
print(labels[0].description)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshooting: Reset host os time (set NTP)

problem was the time difference between host os and guest os.

```
ln -sf / usr / share / zoneinfo / Asia / Seoul / etc / localtime
rdate -s time.bora.net
hwclock --systohc
date
hwclock
```

At `time.bora.net`, find and configure the appropriate ntp(network time protocol) server. Fit your area